# jquery live click behaviour in 1.4.4

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

i m using jquery ui tabs and inside the tabs i m calling jquery live function using a code

now in 1.4.2 i did not had to call the line

```
  $('.show_comment').die('click');
```

but in jquery 1.4.4 i have to call as the "live" function is fired twice on revisiting a tab ( n+1 times on visiting a tab n times)

in jquery 1.4.2 it was fired only once...

as i have long codes i have to add many "die statements"

Any other work around for not adding die calls

The code...

```
      $('#tabs').tabs(
{
    load: function(e, ui) 
    {
        $('.show_comment').die('click');
        if ($('#tabs-2').tabs('option','selected') == 0)
        {
            $('.show_comment').live('click' , function() {
                console.log( $(this).text() );
                /*
                var p = $(this).parents().filter(':eq(6)');
                var bar_cls = p.attr('class');

                $("ol#update li." + bar_cls +" ol li").toggle('fast');
                */

                /*$("ol#update li." + bar_cls +" ol li").children(".nli_comment").corner();*/
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
,
selected: 1,
fx:{height: 'toggle', duration: 'fast'},
spinner: '<em>Loading...</em>' ,
collapsible: true
});
```

Any help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `.bind` instead. I take it that your tab content is loaded in from an ajax source? If so, then binding on the `tabsload` event will result in a new handler getting attached *each time the tab is loaded*, so it makes sense that you need to call `die()` beforehand.

Using `.bind` means that the click handler attached to `.show_comment` will *naturally* die when you load another tab, and will get reattached when `#tabs-2` is loaded again.

Comment: no i want the live as i m adding new DOMs in the tab (more results as in twitter)...see the shouts tab in this page...(http://pradyut.dyndns.org/auser.jsp?id=2)

Comment: @Pradyut - Maybe what you are doing is the right thing? In fact, it sounds like jQuery 1.4.2 was misbehaving.